# Retrieving details from multiple tables using SpringMVC

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am developing a Shopping Application, In my Application i have table tenant and in tenant table i have have column Binary_id which is primary key in binary table in database. Now when i making a get request to tenant table i am getting all the tenant table fields as JSON. But I have @ManyToOne relation from binary table to tenant i.e tenant can have multiple records in binary. So, while making GET call from POSTMAN client instead of getting tenant details, i need to get all the binary records related to that tenant as JSON.

Now i am getting JSON as follows when making a call to  http://localhost:8080/sportsmvc/rest/tenant  from POSTMAN Client

```
[
{
"id": 2,
"binaryId": "1002",
"name": "AltisArena"
},
{
"id": 9,
"binaryId": "1001",
"name": "Agon"
```

}
    ]

But i need the responce JSON As below:

```
      [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "AltisArena",
        "listOfBinary": [
            {
                "tenant_id": 2,
                "location": "location1",
                "description": "ABC"
            },
            {
                "tenant_id": 2,
                "location": "location2",
                "description": "ABCD"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Agon",
        "listOfBinary": [
            {
                "tenant_id": 9,
                "location": "location3",
                "description": "desc1"
            },
            {
                "tenant_id": 9,
                "location": "location4",
                "description": "desc2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Code snippets:

Tenant Entity:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="tenant", catalog="db_sports" )
// Define named queries here
@NamedQueries ( {
  @NamedQuery ( name="TenantEntity.countAll", query="SELECT COUNT(x) FROM TenantEntity x" )
} )
public class TenantEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // ENTITY PRIMARY KEY ( BASED ON A SINGLE FIELD )
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id", nullable=false)
    private Integer    id           ;
    @Column(name="name", nullable=false, length=300)
    private String     name         ;

   //----------------------------------------------------------------------
   // ENTITY LINKS ( RELATIONSHIP )
   //----------------------------------------------------------------------
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="binary_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   private SwaBinaryEntity swaBinary   ;
```

SWA_Binary Entity:

```
       @Entity
@Table(name="SWA_Binary", catalog="db_sports" )
// Define named queries here
@NamedQueries ( {
  @NamedQuery ( name="SwaBinaryEntity.countAll", query="SELECT COUNT(x) FROM SwaBinaryEntity x" )
} )
public class SwaBinaryEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // ENTITY PRIMARY KEY ( BASED ON A SINGLE FIELD )
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Id
    @Column(name="id", nullable=false, length=100)
    private String     id           ;

    @Column(name="file_location", nullable=false, length=400)
    private String     fileLocation ;

    @Column(name="description", nullable=false, length=200)
    private String     description  ;
```

TenantRestController:

```
   @RequestMapping( value="/tenant",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public List<Tenant> findAll() {
    return tenantService.findAll();
}
```

TenantServiceImpl:

```
@Override
public List<Tenant> findAll() {
    List<TenantEntity> entities = tenantPersistence.loadAll();
    List<Tenant> beans = new ArrayList<Tenant>();
    for(TenantEntity entity : entities) {
        beans.add(tenantServiceMapper.mapTenantEntityToTenant(entity));
    }
    return beans;
 }
```

TenantServiceMapper:

```
public Tenant mapTenantEntityToTenant(TenantEntity tenantEntity) {
    if(tenantEntity == null) {
        return null;
    }

    //--- Generic mapping 
    Tenant tenant = map(tenantEntity, Tenant.class);

    //--- Link mapping ( link to SwaBinary )
    if(tenantEntity.getSwaBinary() != null) {
        tenant.setBinaryId(tenantEntity.getSwaBinary().getId());
    }
    return tenant;
}
```

Can anyone please help to to solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why you do not add the @ManyToOne releationship to your entities?

Comment: @Jens Thanks for replay.Sorry forgotten to add,  I edited TenantEntity class.

Comment: Try to add `@ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`

Comment: @Jens getting the response same as before.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstood model, but it seems like it's a bit wrong. In what you need JSON you have tenant that have multiple binaries, but in JPA model it's vise versa and tenant have 1 binary.

In TenantEntity shouldn't it be like this ?:

```
@OneToMany
private List<SwaBinaryEntity> swaBinary
```

Comment: Thanks for replay. Once i will check and let you know

Comment: Changes the annotation as you said. But getting only tenant related JSON. Not getting binary table records related to tenant

Comment: Do you fill all binaries with data in tenantService.findAll() method? Because it seems like you return not persisted entity.

Comment: I edited my post, added findAll() implementation at the end. Is there any issue?

Comment: Need to look deeper. Is method tenantServiceMapper.mapTenantEntityToTenant(entity) iterates over binaries of tenant?

Comment: it is not iterating over binary. It checks if tenant entity is present or not, if not it will return null, if present it will iterate through binary i get the id. I edited my post. added mapper class for tenant

Comment: OK, now if you have SwaBinary as List you need to add field to Tenant class as List<Binary> and fill it in mapTenantEntityToTenant() by iterating over SwaBinary elements